# Add Wine application to GNOME application list

Tags: wine, gnome-shell, 18.10, shortcuts

I have some applications installed with Wine and if I like to start them I always have to open them through the terminal.

Is there an option to put them into the application list as a shortcut so that I can open them through pressing <kbd>super</kbd> and search for the name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a `.desktop` launcher for the application in your `~/.local/share/applications` directory.

To create a simple `.desktop` launcher manually, first create an empty text file, name it `<application-name>.desktop` in the aforementioned directory, and add the following lines to it

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Application Name
Comment=A short description of the application
Exec=command-to-run-application
Icon=/full/path/to/icon-file
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

<sub>Note that in the `Exec=` line you need to use the full path to the command (i.e. `/home/<YOUR_USERNAME>/folder/...` instead of `~/folder/...`).</sub>

Then save the file. If it doesn't appear in '*Show Applications*' (or searching after pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>), log out and re-login.

---

Also there are user-friendly GUI tools to create a `.desktop` launcher, e.g.

- **Main Menu** aka `alacarte`: install by running

  ```
  sudo apt install alacarte
  ```
- **MenuLibre**: install by running

  ```
  sudo apt install menulibre
  ```
- `gnome-desktop-item-edit`: need to install the `gnome-panel` package by running

  ```
  sudo apt install gnome-panel
  ```

  **Note:** `gnome-desktop-item-edit` is [discarded since the Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/q/1184733/480481) release.

Comment: I could create the icon without any problems, but when I click it it does not open the application. I have `Exec= wine /home/<user>/.wine/folder_to_app/app.exe`. Do it need to set Terminal to true, since it works if I use the command in terminal?

Comment: changed it to to `Terminal=ture` and now it works fine. The space after Exec was not on purpose. Thanks a lot.