# gnome-desktop-item-edit: command not found on Ubuntu 19.10 and later even with the 'gnome-panel' package installed

Tags: .desktop, gnome-panel, 19.10

I installed Ubuntu 19.10 and have issues trying to create a desktop icon with `gnome-desktop-item-edit`.

```
$ sudo gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new

  sudo: gnome-desktop-item-edit: command not found

$ which gnome-panel

  /usr/bin/gnome-panel

$ gnome-panel --version

  gnome-panel 3.34.0
```

Is this an issue with Ubuntu 19.10 or a problem with the `gnome-panel` package?

Comment: Please post the part you edited in later as a *separate new question*. I have removed it, but you can find it [here](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1184733/3). The original question was about failure to *create* `.desktop` launchers on 19.10 using `gnome-desktop-item-edit` whereas the edited part is about the failure to *run a specific* `.desktop` launcher on 19.10. Questions should not be edited in a way that they change drastically (refer to [this](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/16366/480481)).

Comment: This is one of many examples of FOSS weakness. There is a gap between developers and end users. People ask for simple things for years and yet nobody from community cares, because there is CLI solution described in 15 threads on 5 forums. Linux needs to solve this in order to enter main stream. Should not be difficult once understood.

Answer (score 30):

Yes, indeed it seems `gnome-desktop-item-edit` [is removed](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-panel/commit/758b548aa9d2b920b6e91664b0de9c414b65f2e9) from the `gnome-panel` package, it won't be available for Ubuntu 19.10 (and most likely later releases).

As an workaround you can create `.desktop` files by hand. Just create a blank text file and add the following lines to it for a simple one:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=<NAME OF THE APPLICATION>
Comment=<A SHORT DESCRIPTION>
Exec=<COMMAND-OR-FULL-PATH-TO-LAUNCH-THE-APPLICATION>
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=<ICON NAME OR PATH TO ICON>
NoDisplay=false
```

Then rename the file as `APPNAME.desktop` and right-click and select '*allow launching*' (you may also have to [make it executable](https://askubuntu.com/q/286621/480481)).

Also the `.desktop` files for installed applications are usually found in your `/usr/share/applications/` directory (or `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/` for snap applications). You can copy a `.desktop` file from there.

For a GUI alternative you may use `alacarte` (aka '*Main Menu*'). Install it by running (the 'universe' repo needs to be enabled)

```
sudo apt install alacarte
```

It creates a `.desktop` launcher in your `~/.local/share/applications/` directory by default (and hence it makes the application available in your list of applications, so that you can launch it from your *Activities* overview or *Applications* overview). You can copy the created `.desktop` file afterwards.

Comment: Can conclude that the last Ubuntu version with [`gnome-desktop-item-edit`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=disco&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=gnome-desktop-item-edit) executable is 19.04 (*disco*).

Comment: Upvoted for the `alacarte`