# Create a quick start launcher

Tags: launcher, gnome-panel

I'm new with Linux, I like but I'm learning how to use it. 
Today I wanted to create a quick launcher for a hard drive where I have data, no OS installed.

I tried this:

```
sudo apt install gnome-panel

sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade

sudo gnome-desktop-item-edit /home/cumpi/Escritorio/ --create-new
```

After this command I have this error:

```
sudo: gnome-desktop-item-edit: orden no encontrada
```

(in English that means order no found).

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184733/gnome-desktop-item-edit-command-not-found-on-ubuntu-19-10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gnome-desktop-item-edit: command not found on Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184733/gnome-desktop-item-edit-command-not-found-on-ubuntu-19-10)

Answer (score 1):

It seems `gnome-desktop-item-edit` is removed from the [`gnome-panel` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=disco&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=bin%2Fgnome-desktop-item-edit), and it is [not available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=eoan&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=bin%2Fgnome-desktop-item-edit) for Ubuntu 19.10 and 20.04 LTS (and most likely later releases).

However, you may try to create a launcher by hand. Make a blank text file and add these lines in it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=<NAME OF THE APPLICATION>
Comment=<A SHORT DESCRIPTION>
Exec=<COMMAND-OR-FULL-PATH>
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=<ICON NAME OR PATH TO ICON>
NoDisplay=false
```

When you save it, rename it to NAME.desktop and make it [executable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286621/how-do-i-run-executable-scripts-in-nautilus)

Hope this will help. Cheers!